# Empty response from post with formData

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fetch, form-data

In VueJS i am trying to perform a post

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('name', 'hey')

fetch('http://homestead.test/api/customers', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: data
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

Added a resource route

```
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');
```

and return the request

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

And my console.log prints the following

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a then after the fetch's then which does not exists.

You can use arrow functions at then for accessing the response variable you got from the request

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('name', 'hey')

fetch('http://homestead.test/api/customers', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: data
})
.then((response) => {
  // now you can access response here
  console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: It gives me a `Promise {<pending>}` response

Comment: my bad, should be right now. If you want to print as json you can use JSON.parse.

Comment: Wats wrong in the question ' s then promise . I guess it is correct only.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be with the content header type it should

```json
{
    Content-type: 'application/json'
}
```

And also try to send the data with:

```
body :JSON.stringify(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why FormData is empty, but all requests with JSON body works.

```
let data = new FormData() 
data.append('name', 'hey')

let json = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data));;
fetch('http://homestead.test/api/customers', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: data
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```